# Why do I keep getting a FormatException error when trying to print and display the result of a calculation (in C#)?

Tags: c#

Currently, I am making a simple calculator. I am trying to display the result of a calculation of two numbers. I have created two TextBlocks in XAML: one for the inputs and one for the output. I have created an 'equals' button to call the various calculation functions. When the equals button is pressed, I get a FormatException error.

I have tried to print the result as a string to the output box with no luck. I also previously had two input boxes but when the equals button was pressed, the result was overriding the second number.

Below is an example of the code:

C#:

```
String calculation;
        double number1;
        double number2;
        double total;

private void Number_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            inputBox.Text += ((Button)sender).Content.ToString();
        }

private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (inputBox.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                number1 = double.Parse(inputBox.Text);

                calculation = "+";
                inputBox.Text = "";
                inputBox.Text = number1 + "+";
            }
        }

private void Equals_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (inputBox.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                number1 = double.Parse(inputBox.Text);

                switch (calculation)
                {
                    case "/":
                        Divide_Calculation();
                        outputBox.Text = total.ToString();
                        break;
                    case "*":
                        Multiply_Calculation();
                        outputBox.Text = total.ToString();
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        Subtract_Calculation();
                        outputBox.Text = total.ToString();
                        break;
                    case "+":
                        Add_Calculation();
                        outputBox.Text = total.ToString();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

 private void Add_Calculation()
        {
            total = number1 + number2;
        }
```

XAML:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="inputBox" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                       Margin="0, 0, 0, 400" Width="340" Height="155" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="outputBox" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                       Margin="0, 100, 0, 400" Width="340" Height="40" />
```

EDIT: Below is the error encountered.

"An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: What's the error message & stack trace?

Comment: `inputBox.Text = number1 + "+"` this line adds `+` to the text block. And then you are trying to parse that value to float `number1 = double.Parse(inputBox.Text);` in equal button click. Text with `+` can not be parsed to double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `inputBox.Text` is a string containing the + symbol. You can't parse that to a `double`. You need to split up the string to contain only numbers before you parse it.

```
char[] delimiters = { '+', '-', '\\', '*' };
string[] inputs = inputBox.Text.Split(delimiters);
if (inputs.Length == 2) {
    bool pass = double.TryParse(inputs[0], out number1);
    pass = double.TryParse(inputs[1], out number2);
}
```

This should give you number1 and number2 given a string of #+#, #-#, #*#, #/#. You probably want to do some error handling with the pass variable. Also, as far as the operator, you can either search for it for your switch, or using calculation should be fine, but you will want to add some error checking to make sure the user doesn't enter multiple operators, or to make sure there is a number before and after the operator.

Comment: Could you please provide the relevant line of code that would achieve this? I'm relatively new to C#.